# Play Framework 2.0, update date, Ebeam cause Data has changed error

Tags: unit-testing, date, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am trying to do unit testing on my Play 2.0 application.

I have a class called patient, below is a simplified version of my class:

```
public class Patient extends Model{
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Required
    public String gender;

    public Date updatedOn;

    public void update(Object o){
        this.updatedOn = new Date();
        super.update(0);
    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine if I update Patient in browser, but when I write unit test and do

```
    Patient patient = new Patient();        
    patient.gender = "M"
    patient.save();
    assertThat(patient.id).isNotNull();
    Long id = patient.id;

    patient = Patient.find.byId(id);
    assertThat(patient).isNotNull();
    assertThat(patient.gender).isEqualTo("M");

    patient.gender = "F";
    assertThat(patient.gender).isEqualTo("F");

    patient.update(patient.id);
```

It will cause an error:

> [ error] Test models.PatientModelTest.updatePatient failed: Data has changed. updated [0] rows sql[update patient set updated_on=? where id=? and date_of_birth=? and gender=? and updated_on=?] bind[null]
>   [error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlHandler.checkRowCount(DmlHandler.java:103)
>   [error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.UpdateHandler.execute(UpdateHandler.java:88)
>   [error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlBeanPersister.execute(DmlBeanPersister.java:86)
>   [error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlBeanPersister.update(DmlBeanPersister.java:66)
>   [error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersistExecute.executeUpdateBean(DefaultPersistExecute.java:91)
>   [error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeNow(PersistRequestBean.java:485)
>   [error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeOrQueue(PersistRequestBean.java:511)
>   [error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.update(DefaultPersister.java:417)
>   [error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.forceUpdate(DefaultPersister.java:184)
>   [error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.update(DefaultServer.java:1651)
>   [error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.update(DefaultServer.java:1640)
>   [error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.update(DefaultServer.java:1617)
>   [error]     at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.update(Ebean.java:548)
>   [error]     at play.db.ebean.Model.update(Model.java:150)
>   [error]     at models.Patient.update(Patient.java:272)
>   [error]     at models.PatientModelTest$4.run(PatientModelTest.java:107)

This is giving me a real headache... please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. Use getter and setter like object.setVariable(newVariable) for updating variable instead of calling straight from the object like object.variable = newVariable. Play will automatically generate getter and setter for all Entity (although it's not seen in your source code).